# How do you stop Intellisense from changing "var" to "VariableDeclarationSyntax" or other similar "Variable" classes?

Tags: visual-studio, intellisense

I'm pretty new to coding in C# and Visual Studio in general, so I don't really know how to stop this issue.  Intellisense is amazing, but it also seems to force its corrections on me, even to the point of ignoring perfect matches.

For example, if I type "var" in all lowercase, Intellisense will open a list of things with "var" in the name.  Instead of choosing the exact match of "var" from the list, it insists that I want "VariableDeclarationSyntax".  I don't.  I want "var" exactly as it is.  I know many people say we should use the full code for C# instead of shorthanding with var, but I can read that from the constructor when I'm working with objects.  It's not worth the time to type.

Similarly, when I created a variable called "service", Intellisense insisted that I wanted "Services" instead of "service".  I can't use a space or tab to just keep "service", so it basically forces me to either use some sort of method for ending Intellisense (I don't know how), or to accept it and then manually change it back.  What kind of "intelligent" program skips right over the variables you created just a line earlier?  My variable "service" is not even in the list of acceptable selections in Intellisense!

Any help or information would be great.  I don't understand why it is ignoring the obvious options (i.e. the ones that match **exactly** by case) and trying to go out of its way to give me suggestions that are WAY out there.

I don't even know where to begin.  Trying to retype it doesn't do anything.  I have to delete back to the beginning capital "V" to start "var" again, and same with "service" when it used "Services".  Then it forces me to pick the same things again when I hit the spacebar or tab. I can manually change the "V" to "v" and then delete everything else, but it's such a hassle.  I can do the same with "Services" to make "service", but again, so much extra work from using something that should be making things easier.  I don't know what would change this.  I searched for something matching this question and nothing came up on Stack Overflow.  Google was also unhelpful.

Here is an image of what's happening.  Notice that I declared a variable just two lines above where I'm working.  I'm attempting to reference the variable I've already made to assign to another variable.  But it doesn't want to give me that option.  Pressing spacebar or tab or semicolon (;) all give me the generated code snippet.  The only thing that seems to stop it is to click away or use the right-arrow to go to a new line and then come back.  What a pain!

[Image of Visual Studio 2022 in action](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U1eye.png)

Comment: From what I can see, Visual Studio uses IntelliCode, not IntelliSense.  I don't know what the real difference is.  I started using Visual Studio Code so I did not realize this difference before I posted.

Comment: Hi, any update on this, have you checked my answer, Would it be able to explain the concepts to you? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:**

I checked the updates of your question.

The situation you said is totally expected.

[Implicitly Typed Local Variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/implicitly-typed-local-variables#remarks)

> var cannot be used on fields at class scope.

[Fields (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/fields)

> A field initializer cannot refer to other instance fields.

So VS intellisense will not give that suggestion, it doesn't match the regulation of C#.

How to disable the space key of acceptting intellisense:

[image]

**Original Answer:**

From your description, the 'intellisense' looks like merely change the the typed code to Class name.

If the question could be more detailed be better, for example, some screenshots.

Based on the words of your question, I can deem of a scenario, your default VS intellisense performance may be altered by some other extensions.

For example, a classic VS extension Resharper has a feature:

[Persisting state of filters](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Using_Filters_in_Code_Completion.html#persisting-state-of-filters)

In this situation, if you filter the intellisense by some means and set only Classes will be filtered, then the default behaviors have been overridden and changes will persist.

As far as I know, VS intellisense should not have a method to persist change the intellisense behavior in filter results.

If you are sure there is no extra extensions on your side. you can try to reset the Visual Studio:

[/ResetSettings (devenv.exe)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/resetsettings-devenv-exe?view=vs-2022)

[Reset all settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/environment-settings?view=vs-2022#reset-all-settings)

or repair the Visual Studio:

[Repair Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/repair-visual-studio?view=vs-2022)

By the way, you can also try to reopen the VS, then check whether the issue still exists(to exclude temporary issue). Or create a new project(to exclude specific project issue.).

**For your situation, a screenshot will be better, is the intellisense only provide classes selections?**

**If not only classes, does it first input var successfully and later changed to classes name?**

Show more details please.

---

For the intellisense implements in Visual Studio and VSCode, they are different.

Visual Studio's intellisense is tightly integrated with the IDE itself. It's implements is older.

VS Code is heavily relies on LSP(Language Server Protocol), it is different and newer.

IntelliCode is just a enhancement intellisense to Visual Studio. It uses machine learning to provide smarter code completion suggestions.

The intellisense may cause your situation, But it is just a extra feature. your can go this place to disable it:

Tools -> Options -> IntelliCode -> General/Advanced.

You can disable all of the settings in intelliCode, it will not make the original intellisense of Visual Studio broken.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I looked at those.  I can't seem to find more settings for it than those and none of those are all that helpful.  However, there have been two updates to Visual Studio that I've installed since asking my question.  The "var" keyword is no longer ignored.  I am getting a bit frustrated that space will do auto-replace as well, especially on words that are in the dictionary.  That never happened when I used Visual Studio Code's Intellisense.

Comment: I have 0 extensions.  I tried disabling IntelliCode, and that only stopped the suggestions on screen.  As I understand it, IntelliSense is still running (something's giving me snippet suggestions), but it still doesn't recognize variables.  I noticed that this only happens inside of a Class.  The Program Main function works just fine.  I disabled all IntelliCode features and it still does it (although with less options available).  So "Service" gets turned into "IServiceProvider" when I hit the spacebar, even though there's a variable available that matches exactly.

Comment: I also tried to repair, but the result is still the same.  I don't see why there are no settings for IntelliSense.  At least on VS Code I could turn off "spacebar to replace text", but that's not a feature in VS Community?

Comment: @retupmoc258 Please take a look of the answer I updated. If this answer helps you, please [accept it as the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) to end this question, this will help others who encounter the similar issue and searching for the answer. :)

Comment: I'll try it when I have a moment. It should resolve part of my issue. However, I don't see why it shouldn't recognize using a previous field as part of a new field. Why should that be an issue (as shown in my picture)? It's perfectly logical to take an existing field and use methods to create a new field. The IntelliSense refuses to let me use the preexisting field as part of the field initializer for another field.

Comment: Yes, that stopped the functionality.  I still think that's ridiculous that you can't reference another field in a new field initializer.  Often times you want both pieces of information and one is derived from the other.